# Can a bash variable be multiline?

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables, multiline

I wrote a script to list path entries and filter them by keywords. I managed to get it work but I had to write the listing in a temporary file, because I could not store it in memory while keeping the line breaks. Is there a better/more appropriate solution?

```
 #! /bin/bash
tr ':' '\n' <<< $PATH > tmp
if (( $# > 0 )); then
  for W
  do
    grep $W < tmp
  done
else
  cat tmp
fi
rm tmp
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, a variable can contain newlines.  You need to quote the variable while using it.  Your script can be written as:

```
tmp=$(tr ':' '\n' <<< $PATH)
if (( $# > 0 )); then
  for W; do
    grep $W <<< "$tmp"
  done
else
  echo "$tmp"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks! I should have put more quotes in my pocket before trying to improve my bash skills ;-)

Comment: @user1770724 Consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it worked for you.  You might also want to refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

The following will print directories in `PATH` that match the regular expression in `keyword`. It operates in a subshell to isolate the change made to `IFS`.

```
(IFS=:;
 for W in $PATH; do
    if [[ $W =~ $keyword ]]; then
        echo "$W"
    fi
 done
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for W in `echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n'`;
do
   grep <Search pattern> $W
done
```

Check whether this helps to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for helping.
Actually, I want to do the grep the reverse way
I was also trying to learn how to get my bash more readable, espacially by avoiding all the indirection signs that make myself unable to understand what I wrote the day before.